# Sum a range of cells in a single column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have three columns in a DataFrame.  I want to take the number in the Streak_Count column and sum up that number of cells from the returns in the MON TOTAL.  The result is displayed in the WANTED RESULT as shown below.  The issue I cant figure out is summing the number of cells which can be any number>> in this example between 1 and 4.

```
              MON TOTAL STREAK_COUNT    WANTED RESULT
1/2/1992       1.123077       1          1.123077 (only 1 so 1.12)
2/3/1992      -1.296718       0 
3/2/1992      -6.355612       2          -7.65233 (sum of -1.29 and -6.35)
4/1/1992       5.634692       0 
5/1/1992       4.180605       2          9.815297 (sum of 5.63 and 4.18)
7/1/1992      -0.101016       0 
8/3/1992      -0.706125       2         -0.807141 (sum of -.10 and -.706)
10/1/1992      0.368579       0 
11/2/1992      3.822277       0 
1/4/1993       2.233359       0 
2/1/1993       15.219644      4         21.643859
3/1/1993       -2.647693      1         -2.647693
4/1/1993       1.599094       1         1.599094
```

Comment: do you want some special pandas function or looping would work?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about finding the right thing to group by. In this case, a reversed cumulative sum of `STREAK_COUNT` will give you what you want.

First we create the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'MON TOTAL':[1.123077, -1.296178, -6.355612, 5.634692, 4.180605, -0.101016, -0.706125,
                                    0.368579, 3.822277, 2.233359, 15.219644, -2.647693, 1.599094],
                       'STREAK_COUNT':[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1]},
                      index=['1/2/1992', '2/3/1992', '3/2/1992', '4/1/1992', '5/1/1992', '7/1/1992', '8/3/1992',
                             '10/1/1992', '11/2/1992', '1/4/1993', '2/1/1993', '3/1/1993', '4/1/1993'])
>>> df
           MON TOTAL  STREAK_COUNT
1/2/1992    1.123077             1
2/3/1992   -1.296178             0
3/2/1992   -6.355612             2
4/1/1992    5.634692             0
5/1/1992    4.180605             2
7/1/1992   -0.101016             0
8/3/1992   -0.706125             2
10/1/1992   0.368579             0
11/2/1992   3.822277             0
1/4/1993    2.233359             0
2/1/1993   15.219644             4
3/1/1993   -2.647693             1
4/1/1993    1.599094             1
```

Next find the groups, compute the sum of each group, and join the results to the original dataframe:

```
>>> groups = df['STREAK_COUNT'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
>>> df['RESULT'] = df.groupby(groups)['MON TOTAL'].transform('sum')
>>> df
           MON TOTAL  STREAK_COUNT     RESULT
1/2/1992    1.123077             1   1.123077
2/3/1992   -1.296178             0  -7.651790
3/2/1992   -6.355612             2  -7.651790
4/1/1992    5.634692             0   9.815297
5/1/1992    4.180605             2   9.815297
7/1/1992   -0.101016             0  -0.807141
8/3/1992   -0.706125             2  -0.807141
10/1/1992   0.368579             0  21.643859
11/2/1992   3.822277             0  21.643859
1/4/1993    2.233359             0  21.643859
2/1/1993   15.219644             4  21.643859
3/1/1993   -2.647693             1  -2.647693
4/1/1993    1.599094             1   1.599094
```

If you just want results for the end of each streak, then use a mask to filter it:

```
>>> df[df['STREAK_COUNT'] > 0]
          MON TOTAL  STREAK_COUNT     RESULT
1/2/1992   1.123077             1   1.123077
3/2/1992  -6.355612             2  -7.651790
5/1/1992   4.180605             2   9.815297
8/3/1992  -0.706125             2  -0.807141
2/1/1993  15.219644             4  21.643859
3/1/1993  -2.647693             1  -2.647693
4/1/1993   1.599094             1   1.599094
```

Comment: jakevdp great answer, you can also use builtin cumsum i.e `df.groupby(df['STREAK_COUNT'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1])['MON TOTAL'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1:**

Efficient version that performs operations on entire column rather than iterating through and utilizes object/iterator thus avoiding lists.

The changes here are that,

1) We first get Series for "STREAK_COUNT" and convert to `tuple` with index as first value and "STREAK_COUNT" as second using `enumerate`. Since `enumerate` is an iterable, we can use it directly  in step(3) instead of converting to list.

2) Define `getTotal()` function and process to each value in the (1) independently to generate corresponding "RESULT" value.

3) map `getTotal()` to entire "STREAK_COUNT" enumerate object generated in step(1) to get desired "RESULT" column.

**Working Code**

```
def getTotal(x):        
        pos = [i for i in range(x[0],x[0]-x[1],-1)]
        total = sum(df.iloc[pos, 0])
        func = lambda x : x if x !=0 else ''
        return func(total)


df[ "RESULT" ] = map(lambda x: getTotal(x), enumerate(df["STREAK_COUNT"]))
print df
```

**Older Version**

Not as efficient since we need to iterate through rows and columns, but works for any values within STREAK_COUNT and more clear to understand.

**Sample Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", index_col = 0)

#iterate over rows with index
for idx, (lab, row) in  enumerate(df.iterrows()):
        #get current STREAK_COUNT value
    count = int(df.iloc[idx, 1])

    #get previous positions based on count
    pos = [i for i in range(idx,idx-count,-1)]

    #count total
    total = sum(df.iloc[pos, 0])

    #create new column value based on total
    func = lambda x : x if x !=0 else ''
    df.loc[lab, "RESULT"] = func(total)

print df
```

**RESULT**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
           MON TOTAL  STREAK_COUNT    RESULT
1/2/1992    1.123077             1   1.12308
2/3/1992   -1.296718             0          
3/2/1992   -6.355612             2  -7.65233
4/1/1992    5.634692             0          
5/1/1992    4.180605             2    9.8153
7/1/1992   -0.101016             0          
8/3/1992   -0.706125             2 -0.807141
10/1/1992   0.368579             0          
11/2/1992   3.822277             0          
1/4/1993    2.233359             0          
2/1/1993   15.219644             4   21.6439
3/1/1993   -2.647693             1  -2.64769
4/1/1993    1.599094             1   1.59909
>>>
```

Comment: @jakevdp is there a way to take you code and show a blank row if it is not the end of the streak.  So if there is a 0 in the column then you would not display anything (or NaN) in the WANTED RESULT column.  Let me know if that is possible.

Comment: @J Westwood , pls checkout my updates that's more efficient as it now works directly on entire column achieving desired result.