# How do you sum up with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How do you sum up only the steel with Pandas?

```
Date                   Material         Quantity
10-12-2020             steel            2
12-12-2020             steel            5
13-12-2020             steel            6
14-12-2020             glass            1
15-12-2020             glass            2
16-12-2020             plastic          10
```

So, far I have done this, which displays only the 'steel' material, but I have difficulties to sum them:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('materials.cvs')
total_materials = df.groupby('material')
materials = total_materials.get_group('steel')
print(materials)
```

Comment: Looks like someone has already answered this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133983/sum-a-range-of-cells-in-a-single-column-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
steel = df.loc[df['Material'] == 'steel']
total = steel['Quantity'].sum()
print("Result: "+str(total))
```

Comment: ValueError: No axis named Quantity for object type DataFrame

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: That is because you are trying to print it out along with some text or simiar. Then you need to wrap the numeric value between str(). Check the upate

Comment: Thank you for your promp response.